# Date format dd:mm:yy:hh:mm:ss to a dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss

Tags: vba, datetime, excel

I want to use VBA to convert the date stored on a file in the format `dd:mm:yy:hh:mm:ss` to something usable for sorting in excel using VBA to process files.  I can't find anything that is compact.  I have tried text to columns and then combine the values separated out back into a date and a time but this is cumbersome and slow for big data files.

Anyone know a quick method that can be used??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this to convert dates in the range `A1:A10`:

```
[A1:A10]=[IF({1},TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A10,":",""),"00\/00\/00  00\:00\:00"))]
```

Comment: + 1 Nice one lori as usual. Wouldn't this also help? `=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,8),":","/") & " " & RIGHT(A1,8)`

Comment: Yes, that way might be more efficient.

Comment: Lori_m , thanks so much that did the trick .  Siddharth,  I tried you sugestion and it produced "#NAME?" not sure what the issue was there .

Comment: try with: `[A1:A10]=[IF({1},SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1:A10,8),":","/") & " " & RIGHT(A1:A10,8))]`. You can enter this from the immediate window, if you want to include in code it would be better to replace `A1:A10` by a named range like `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim dtStr As String
Dim dtArr() As String
Dim rebuildDt As String
Dim dtDte As Date
Dim dtStr2 As String


dtStr = "29:08:12:23:37:04"
dtArr = Split(dtStr, ":")
rebuildDt = dtArr(0) & "/" & dtArr(1) & "/" & dtArr(2) _
    & " " & dtArr(3) & ":" & dtArr(4) & ":" & dtArr(5)

dtDte = CDate(rebuildDt)
dtStr2 = Format(dtDte, "dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss")
Debug.Print dtStr2

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` function and parse out the string since you will (assuming here) have `dd:mm:yy:hh:mm:ss`  so first three are the date and last three are the time.

Comment: the first suggestion by @yosukesabai

Answer (score 0):

A quick way You could use the code below to

1. Read in the `DateLastModified` of all the files in a certain folder into an array
2. Dump and sort the array in a temporary worksheet
3. Store the sorted array (in a variable `Y` below)

**Code**

```
Sub GetFiles()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim strFolder As String
Dim strFileName As String
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim X()
Dim Y
Dim ws As Worksheet

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.DisplayAlerts = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With

strFolder = "c:\temp"
strFileName = Dir(strFolder & "\*.*")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.getfolder(strFolder)

ReDim X(1 To objFolder.Files.Count, 1 To 2)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
X(lngCnt, 1) = objFile.Name
X(lngCnt, 2) = objFile.datelastmodified
Next

Set ws = Sheets.Add
ws.[a1].Resize(UBound(X, 1), 2) = X
ws.Range("A:B").Sort ws.Range("B1"), xlDescending
Y = ws.[a1].Resize(UBound(X, 1), 2)
ws.Delete

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.DisplayAlerts = True
.EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

a method using only Excel formula, no VBA

`=DATE(2000+MID(A1,7,2),MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,8))`

I assumed that, for example, 1am is expressed as 01:00:00, i.e. not dropping reading zero anywhere, always two characters for each of 6 elements.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, yeah, you are right.  i am a good candidate for those bad programmers, making things work the way i want, dont care much about real consequences.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple VBA function:

```
Function ConvertDateFormat(dateInOldFormat As String)
    Dim d As Date
    Dim ss() As String
    ss = Split(dateInOldFormat, ":")
    d = DateSerial(CInt(ss(2)), CInt(ss(1)), CInt(ss(0))) _
        + TimeSerial(CInt(ss(3)), CInt(ss(4)), CInt(ss(5)))
    ConvertDateFormat = Format(d, "dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss")
End Function
```

Usage:

```
s = ConvertDateFormat("30:08:12:08:52:11")
'returns "30/08/12 08:52:11"
```

Here I'm not even going to consider dealing with [Y2K](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y2K) issues... Internally in this function I'm assuming that year "12" means 12 AD, but this makes no difference in the end result which has a 2-digit year anyway.